# how can i get the messages in gmail/email client inbox folder?

Tags: android, email

i would just like to ask on how can i get the messages on my email inbox folder
and display it?
similarly, how can I access gmail's inbox or other mail client's inbox folder? is this possible on android?

Answer (score 2):

There is no formal support for this on android. There's a hack where you use the gmail-ls content provider but from what I've gathered that doesn't work on the latest versions of android (see [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/1148f0794e397a4c/7e29628753e82f5a?lnk=raot) for details). If you want to used the gmail-ls content provider [check out this](http://www.thisismobility.com/blog/2011/01/17/fetching-gmail-messages-by-label-on-android/) for an example, but remember this is a hack and not formally supported. So don't be surprised if/when it doesn't work.

You might want to take a look at something like [gmail4j](http://g4j.sourceforge.net/). It doesn't have the nice integration that a formal content-provider would but it has at least it has a known api.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class EmailinboxActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    EmailManager emailManager;
    private String stmpHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String mailServer = "imap.gmail.com";    
    public String urlServer = "gmail.com";
    public String username = " Any Gmail Username";
    public String password = " Any Gmail Password";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        emailManager=new EmailManager(username, password, urlServer, stmpHost, mailServer);
        try {
//          emailManager.getInboxMails();           
            emailManager.close();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}


//

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
    private byte[] data;   
    private String type;   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
        this.type = type;   
    }   
    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
    }   
    public void setType(String type) {   
        this.type = type;   
    }   
    public String getContentType() {   
        if (type == null)   
            return "application/octet-stream";   
        else  
            return type;
    }   
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
    }   
    public String getName() {   
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
    }   
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
    }   
} 


//

public class EmailAccount {
    public String urlServer = "gmail.com";
    public String username = "username";
    public String password = "password";
    public String emailAddress;
    public EmailAccount(String username, String password, String urlServer) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.urlServer = urlServer;
        this.emailAddress = username + "@" + urlServer;
    }
}

//

public class EmailAuthenticator extends Authenticator   {
    private EmailAccount account;
    public EmailAuthenticator(EmailAccount account) {
        super();
        this.account = account;
    }
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
        return new PasswordAuthentication(account.emailAddress, account.password);  
    } 
}

//


package com.android.emailinbox;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import android.location.Address;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EmailManager {
    private String stmpHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String mailServer = "imap.gmail.com";
    private EmailAccount account;
    private Session smtpSession; 
    private Session imapSession; 

    private Folder inbox,sentMail;
    private Store store,sentstore;
      boolean isSet;
    public EmailManager(String username, String password, String urlServer, String stmpHost, String mailServer) {
        account = new EmailAccount(username, password, urlServer);
        this.stmpHost = stmpHost;
        this.mailServer = mailServer;
        initProtocol();
    }
    private void initProtocol() {
        EmailAuthenticator authenticator = new EmailAuthenticator(account);     
        Properties props1 = new Properties();  
        props1.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");  
        props1.setProperty("mail.host", stmpHost);  
        props1.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
        props1.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");  
        props1.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");  
        props1.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
        props1.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");  
        props1.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");  
        smtpSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props1, authenticator); 

        Properties props2 = new Properties();
        props2.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", mailServer);
        props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
        props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        imapSession = Session.getInstance(props2);
    }   
    public void getInboxMails() throws MessagingException {
        store = imapSession.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect(mailServer, account.username, account.password);
        inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
//      List<Address>addresses=new ArrayList<Address>();

        for (int i = messages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {

             Part p = messages[i]; 
            try {
                String subject = messages[i].getSubject();
                Log.v("subject","subject="+subject);
                String body=getText(p);
                Log.v("body","body="+body);
                javax.mail.Address[] address=messages[i].getFrom();
                String add=address.toString().trim();
                Log.v("address","address="+add);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return ;
    }
    /*public void getsentMails() throws MessagingException {
        sentstore = imapSession.getStore("imaps");
        sentstore.connect(mailServer, account.username, account.password);
        sentMail = sentstore.getFolder("Sent");
        sentMail.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] sentmessages = sentMail.getMessages();
        Log.v("messages","messages"+sentmessages);
        Log.v("messages","messages"+sentmessages.length);

        for (int i = sentmessages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {

             Part p = sentmessages[i]; 
            try {
                String sentsubject = sentmessages[i].getSubject();
                Log.v("sentsubject","sentsubject="+sentsubject);
                String sentbody=getText(p);
                Log.v("sentbody","sentbody="+sentbody);
                javax.mail.Address[] address=messages[i].getFrom();
                String add=address.toString().trim();
                Log.v("address","address="+add);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

        return ;



    }*/
    public void close() {
        //Close connection 
        try {
//          inbox.close(false);
//          store.close();
            sentMail.close(false);
            sentstore.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
    /*public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {  
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(smtpSession);
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));  
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));  
        message.setSubject(subject);  
        message.setDataHandler(handler);  
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)  
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));  
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));  
        Transport.send(message);  
    } */
    public String getText(Part p) throws MessagingException, IOException {

        if (p.isMimeType("text/*")) {
            boolean textIsHtml = false;
            String s = (String) p.getContent();

            textIsHtml = p.isMimeType("text/html");
            return String.valueOf(s);
        }

        if (p.isMimeType("multipart/alternative")) {
            // prefer html text over plain text
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) p.getContent();
            String text = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                Part bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);
                if (bp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                    if (text == null)
                        text = getText(bp);
                    continue;
                } else if (bp.isMimeType("text/html")) {
                    String s = getText(bp);
                    if (s != null)
                        return String.valueOf(s);
                } else {
                    return getText(bp);
                }
            }
            return text;
        } else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) p.getContent();
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                String s = getText(mp.getBodyPart(i));
                if (s != null)
                    return String.valueOf(s);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```