# How To display gmail inbox in list view in my activity in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to display my `Gmail` inbox's all mails in `ListView` of my `Activity` in android. Kindly direct me in a related direction.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11389614/940096) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4182169/940096)

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented and supported Intent to open the Gmail inbox. There might not even be a Gmail inbox on any given device, either because the app is not there or because the user is not using it.

Answer (score 0):

**Example of fetching the most recent unread messages**

***Reference Link:***http://www.thisismobility.com/blog/2011/01/17/fetching-gmail-messages-by-label-on-android/

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

Cursor unread = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls/conversations/xxxxxx@gmail.com"),null, "label:^u", null, null);

unread.moveToFirst();

int subjectIdx = unread.getColumnIndex("subject");

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buffer);
do {

```
String subject = unread.getString(subjectIdx);

tv.append(subject + "\n");
```

} while (unread.moveToNext());